# Avoid background flickr when jumping from page to page

Tags: html, css, browser

We've got simple

```
body{background:black;}
```

Background is black. When you just jump from one black background page to another one, in fact during reloading background gets white for about 0,1s. Its kinnda logical thing while browser is re-rendering all the page. But is it possible to avoid it somehow?

Comment: Only if you avoid the page reload in the first place. You could implement something like [pjax](http://pjax.heroku.com/) pretty painlessly.

Comment: You might try `html {background: black}` on those pages; it may cause the initial look to be `black` not `white` (even before `body` load). Not sure if it will work, which is why I posted as a comment.